# Laravel - API RESTful

Tags: php, laravel

Estou seguindo um tutorial, para a criação de uma aplicação *Rest* em *Laravel*, na segunda parte deste tutorial [Laravel -parte2](https://rafaell-lycan.com/2016/construindo-restful-api-laravel-parte-2/), quando uso o comando:

```
php artisan route:list
```

Exibe este erro

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Controller' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-api\app\Http\Controllers\JobsController.php on line 11

[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
   Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Controller' not found
```

Meus *controlller*

```
class JobsController extends Controller{

public function index()
{
    $jobs = Job::with('company')->get();
    return response()->json($jobs);//retornando um tipo json
}


class CompaniesController extends Controller{

public function index()
{
    $companies = Company::all();
    return response()->json($companies);
}
```

Se alguém souber algum outro tutorial pra eu sacar também, estou disponível.

Answer (score 0):

De alguma forma Laravel não está conseguindo encontrar o seu **JobsController**, execute

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Em seguida, verifique o arquivo vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php, seu **JobsController** deve estar lá, caso contrário, o composer não será capaz de fazer autoload e o *Laravel* não terá acesso a ele.

Se você não consegue encontrar seus controladores, você deve verificar:

1) O seu arquivo composer.json, a pasta onde os seus controladores devem estar:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/controllers",
                  ....
    ],
```

2) Verifique se suas classes são nomeadas corretamente.

3) Se você estiver usando um namespace:

A classe **JobsController** extende o **Controller** {...}

Você deve usar o *namespace* em suas referências.

4) Compare as classes que você possui em autoload_classmap.php com as que não estão lá. Deve haver uma diferença na colocação de nomeação ou diretório.

5) Verifique se suas classes começam com

```
<?php
```

e não apenas

```
<?
```

Isso pode não fazer muita diferença para o composer nem o PHP, mas faz para o Laravel.

> [Problema Semelhante](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-51-php-artisal-routelist-fatal-error?page=0)